# How do I remove the time from a feed published date

Tags: javascript, google-feed-api

I have created an RSS feed using Google Feed API and I need to remove the 'published time' from the Published date and only show the 'Date'.

I have this piece of code.

```
function rssfeedsetup() {
    var feedpointer = new google.feeds.Feed(feedurl) //Google Feed API method
    feedpointer.setNumEntries(feedlimit) //Google Feed API method
    feedpointer.load(displayfeed) //Google Feed API method
}

function displayfeed(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
        var thefeeds = result.feed.entries
        for (var i = 0; i < thefeeds.length; i++)
            rssoutput += "<li><a href='" + thefeeds[i].link + "'>" + thefeeds[i].publishedDate + "</a></li>"
        rssoutput += "</ul>"

        feedcontainer.innerHTML = rssoutput
    }
    else
        alert("Error fetching feeds!")
}

window.onload = function () {
    rssfeedsetup()
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a date in javascript with your **publishedDate string** and extract *year*, *month* and *day*.

```
var dt = new Date(thefeeds[i].publishedDate);
dt.getFullYear() + '/' + (dt.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + dt.getDate();
```

> getMonth() you need +1 cuz getMonth return array, so its start in 0